# How do I extract contents within rel in <a> tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rel

```
<a href="#" class="tip" rel="&nbsp;
    Principal Name - S. BALKAR SINGH
    Mobile No. - 8146611008
    Email ID - gsssdhapaiasr@gmail.com
    &nbsp;" style="user-select: text;">View Contact Details<span 
class="caret"></span></a>
```

Principal name, mobile number and email id are the contents I'm interested in. When I specify `soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})` it gives me only "View Contact Details".

Is there a way to extract contents within `rel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rel` is attribute so you have to use `['rel']` - ie. `soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})['rel']`

Working example

```
data = '''<a href="#" class="tip" rel="&nbsp;
    Principal Name - S. BALKAR SINGH
    Mobile No. - 8146611008
    Email ID - gsssdhapaiasr@gmail.com
    &nbsp;" style="user-select: text;">View Contact Details<span 
class="caret"></span></a>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})

print('text:', item.text)
print(' rel:', item['rel'])
print(' rel:', ' '.join(item['rel']))
```

Result:

```
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'S.', 'BALKAR', 'SINGH', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8146611008', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'gsssdhapaiasr@gmail.com', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - S. BALKAR SINGH Mobile No. - 8146611008 Email ID - gsssdhapaiasr@gmail.com
```

---

`BS` for `rel` returns list, not one string, because [Multi-valued attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes)

---

**EDIT:** to get table with data you have to send `POST` request with all data which normally send browser to server - it means data in form, it can be even empty string but server has to receive form fields.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

# form fields send to server
params = {
    'SchoolType': '',
    'Dist1': '',    
    'Sch1': '', 
    'SearchString': ''  
}

r = requests.post('http://www.registration.pseb.ac.in/School/Schoollist', headers=headers, data=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_a = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'tip'})

for items in all_a:
    print('text:', item.text)
    print(' rel:', item['rel'])
    print(' rel:', ' '.join(item['rel']))
    print('-----')
```

Result:

```
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
text: View Contact Details
 rel: ['', 'Principal', 'Name', '-', 'POONAM', 'POONI', 'Mobile', 'No.', '-', '8568940353', 'Email', 'ID', '-', 'GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM', '']
 rel:  Principal Name - POONAM POONI Mobile No. - 8568940353 Email ID - GAURAVGUPTA806@YAHOO.COM 
-----
```

Comment: I get 'NoneType object not subscriptable' error when I use `soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})['rel']` url==>http://www.registration.pseb.ac.in/School/Schoollist#

Comment: it means that `soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})` gives you `None`, and you shouldn't get even `"View Contact Details"`. Code with example HTML works for me.

Comment: if you read directly your url (request GET) then there is no data with `<a class="tip">` and `soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})` gives `None` and you can't use `["rel"]`. You have to read it as POST and then you can get `<a class="tip">` but to make sure you can still check if `soup.find('a', {'class':'tip'})` not gives `None`

Comment: when I use parsehub I get "View Contact Detail". But when I use beautifulsoup I get "NoneType object not subscriptable" error

Comment: Problem is not BeautifulSoup but how do you get this page - with `requests.get()` you get page without data, with `requests.post()` you can send "searching data" and it will return page with results in table.

Comment: requests.post() returns the same NoneType not subscriptable error

Comment: `post()` should send form field to server to get results. see code in answer.